# IntegerField django

Tags: python, django

Не могу сделать систему для просмотров моих статей. Я попробовал так, но не добавляется просмотр.

Файл models:

```
prosmotr = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Файл views:

```
prosmget =  HttpResponse("prosmview")
    if prosmget:
        instance.prosmotr += 1

templates
```

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на эту ссылку автоматический добавился просмотр

```
<a name="prosmview" 
          href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">
             {{ obj.title }}
    </a>
```

Comment: instance.save() надо делать после изменения числа просмотров. Делаете?

Comment: Да уже сделал но если обновляю страницу то просмотры добовляються

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит отделить программную логику подсчёта просмотров от логики отображения статей, чтобы соблюсти принцип единственной ответственности. Да и хранение информации о количестве просмотров лучше вынести в отдельную модель, что позволит сделать эту функцию более универсальной и в последствии применять не только к статьям.

**models.py**

```
class PageHit(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(unique=True)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Подсчёт просмотров - эти типичная сквозная функциональность, которая хорошо реализуется декораторами.

**decorators.py**

```
from functools import wraps
from django.db.models import F
from django.db import transactions

def counted(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transactions.atomic():
            counter, created = PageHit.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)
            counter.count = F('count') + 1
            counter.save()
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

**views.py**

```
from .decorators import counted
from .models import Article

@counted
def show_article(request, pk):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'article_details.html', {'article': article})
```

После этого каждое обращение к представлению `show_article` будет увеличивать счётчик записи в `PageHit` с соответствующим адресом.

Для отображения количества просмотров в шаблоне, можно сделать специальный [тег](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)

**templatetags/counter.py**

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def page_views(context, url=None):
    if url is None:
        request = context.get('request')
        url = request.path
    page_hit = (PageHit.objects
                       .filter(url=url)
                       .first())
    if page_hit is None:
        return ''
    return page_hit.count
```

**article_list.html**

```
{% load counter %}

{% for article in articles %}
    <div class="article">
        <h4>{{ article.title }}</h4>
        <div>
            {{ article.text|truncatewords_html:50|safe }}
        </div>
        <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">Подробнее</a>
        <span>Просмотров: {% page_views article.get_absolute_url %}</span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за код но пока он не работает придется разобраться мой код проекта немножко другой.